# Find index for x closest to each other values in a array in R

Tags: r

Aiming to an existing way or built a function for returning index of x values that are the closest to each other in an vector in R. Here's an example

```
a <- c(10,85,20,75,80,5,105)

# function definition

getIndex <- function(x, n) { 
}

# with x: vector to test and n: number of closest value to detect

# desired function output : and index identifying x closest values in the vector x

ind <- c(0,1,0,1,1,0,0) # or a a logical F,T,F,T,T,F,F # here with n = 3 (looking for 3 closest values)`
```

Comment: This is a clustering problem and the solution depends on how do you define "closest 3 numbers". Minimum distance? Median or mean distance? Range? For example, consider this vector: `c(2, 4, 6, 22, 23)`. Depending on your definition of "closest", you can either get `c(2, 4, 6)` or `c(22, 23, 6)` as your three closest numbers.

Comment: looking for smallest difference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done by looking for the smallest difference between every `i`th and and `(i+n-1)`th elements of the sorted vector. The smallest difference will give you the closest n numbers.

Here's a way with base R -

```
getIndex <- function(x, n) {
  x_s <- sort(x)
  rolling_diff <- c(x_s[n:length(x_s)], rep(NA, n-1)) - x_s
  w <- which.min(rolling_diff)
  x %in% x_s[w:(w+n-1)]
}

getIndex(a, 3)
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

**Benchmarks -**

```
set.seed(2)
x <- sample(1000, 100)
identical(getIndex_Shree(x, 3), getIndex_Ronak(x, 3))
# [1] TRUE
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  shree = getIndex_Shree(x, 3),
  ronak = getIndex_Ronak(x, 3),
  times = 10
)

Unit: microseconds
  expr        min          lq         mean      median         uq         max neval
 shree      81.64      85.838     134.3092     162.346     166.08     174.476    10
 ronak 3157301.98 3249876.496 3308635.5102 3316360.354 3369009.09 3423373.176    10
```

Comment: Excellent answer in base R so defined as accepted answer.

Comment: OMG...I guess that is because of using `combn` twice.

Comment: @RonakShah Probably. I knew the moment I saw `combn` that it's not going to fly but this was a surprise to me as well. Had to bring down length of `x` to 100 and `neval` to 10 just to get some results. :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is one solution using `combn`, where we find difference of every 3 values, take their absolute sum and find the minimum value from them and create a logical vector finding them in original vector.

```
get_closest_values <- function(a, n) {
    index <- which.min(colSums(abs(combn(a, n, diff))))
    a %in% strsplit(combn(a, n, paste, collapse = "-")[index], "-")[[1]]
}

get_closest_values(a, 3)
#[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: Excellent answer

Answer (score 0):

Use -

**UPDATE**

```
library(data.table)
a <- c(10,85,20,75,80,5,105)
getIndex <- function(x, n) {
  a_ <- sort(x)
  diff <- abs(shift(a_) - a_)
  return(seq(1,length(x)) %in% sort(diff, index.return=T)$ix[1:n])
}
getIndex(a, 3)
```

**Output**

```
> getIndex(x, n)
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: I don't think that is the answer – the question was about any three values which are closest.

Comment: @Vivek I tried to benchmark your solution but think it's missing step size in `shift` so not getting correct results for other cases.